# random_int generating values less than minimum

Tags: php, random, passwords, generator

I am generating passwords with `random_int`, but I noticed something weird. Sometimes (purely random), it generates a password less than the minimum value. For example, I set `10` and `15` the limits and once every circa `50-70` tries it pops out a `2-3` character long password. Is there something wrong with my script? It's hard to reproduce the output, just refresh the *script* till you get a similar result.

```
<?php 

    $r_number = random_int( 10 , 15 );

    function random_str(
        $length,
        $keyspace = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,./<>?;:"|[]{}-=_+`~!@#$%^&*'
    ) {
        $str = '';
        $max = mb_strlen($keyspace, '8bit') - 1;
        if ($max < 1) {
            throw new Exception('$keyspace must be at least two characters long');
        }
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
            $str .= $keyspace[random_int(0, $max)];
        }
        return $str;
    }

    $password = random_str($r_number);

    echo $password;

?>
```

Comment: Are you just trying to get a random string between 10 and 15 characters n length? if so, there's better ways to do this.

Comment: can you give me an example!?

Comment: Have you ever seen a password generated with a `<` in it?

Comment: Is that script executed on CLI or by a web browser?

Comment: @tkausl Defy tradition! ✊️

Comment: @deceze I'm confused - what does that mean?

Comment: @tkausl It means *go forth and generate passwords with `<`s in them, not caring about established precedent.* – Though I suspect your comment wasn't meant like that.

Comment: @deceze Ah I see, no I was talking about the script OP posted, I suspected the same as Niet in their answer and was just trying to confirm whether I'm right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going on a limb here, but...

If the generated password happens to include `<` - which is in your default `$keyspace` - and you are viewing the results in a browser, then the `<` is treated as the start of an HTML tag and won't be displayed, nor will anything after it unless a `>` happens to be chosen.

That's the only thing I can think of that would be causing this. Try `echo htmlspecialchars($password);` to output it.